# Open a Website url in new tab PHP

Tags: php, html

I have the following PHP code

```
<?php
$q = rawurlencode($_POST["name"]); // input from textbox 1
$ft = $_POST["ftype"]; //input from textbox 2
```

That I want to open `http://www.example.com/$ft%20$q` in a new tab when the user clicks a button. Is this possible?

I already tried `curl_init`

```
$h = curl_init("http://www.example.com/$ft%20$q");
curl_exec($h);
```

but that did not achieve the desired results.

Could someone explain the proper way to open a new tab in the user's browser?

Comment: You can't do this with PHP. You need to use html's `target` attribute in the `<a>` tag or use JavaScript for this.

Comment: You want to open a URL in a new tab via PHP?

Comment: so this can only done with html???
the main prob is that the url created with respect to the value from user than how can i put it inside html target="_blank :(

Comment: If it can't be done in PHP that means it's a duplicate of one of these http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=open+new+tab. This has certainly been asked and answered before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have POST data, then you have some form on the site, right? Then you can open it in a new tab like this:

HTML

```
<form id="form1" action="http://www.example.com/$ft%20$q" method="post" target="_blank">
   <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
   <input type="text" id="ftype" name="ftype" />
   //submit
</form>
```

JQUERY

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var ft = "";
   var q = "";

   function createURL() {
       $("#form1").attr("action", "http://www.example.com/" + ft + "%20" + q);
   }

   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#name").keyup(function () { 
           q = $("#name").val();
           createURL();
       });

       $("#ftype").keyup(function () { 
           ft = $("#ftype").val();
           createURL();
       });
   });
</script>
```

And a working code at jsfiddle with demonstration of url changing. http://jsfiddle.net/Driveash/7p6BN/

Comment: Hi drive, but in the case of url http://www.example.com/$ft%20$q
the $ft and $q is the value from textboxes :(

Comment: @Hariprasad.ka Try this now. I have also posted link to jsfiddle with example how url will change. It works.

Answer (score 0):

You must do this functionality in your HTML using the target attribute on your anchor tag with the `_blank` value, like this

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Click Me!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't open tabs in PHP as PHP is server side code, not client side.

Read this answer for the explanation of the difference:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/171210

Comment: It is the other way around, PHP is server side.

Comment: Woops, wrote too fast. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This might not be the best way, but if you are on a page with strictly PHP, you could always echo out some basic JavaScipt and just inject the variables.

```
echo ("<script>window.open(\"" . $link . "\");</script");
```